# arrayformula cheking strings on all sheet cells

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, nested-if

I have a code to check strings and I'm not able to put it in an arrayformula, if anyone can help I'd be grateful!
where's a copy of my sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10mkrxCLGkOcKrm481jnsMdQTlf_kgoXUF3eWLKJnKS0/edit?usp=sharing

```
=IF(AND(
MID(A5,8,1)=MID(A5,5,1),MID(A5,2,1)=MID(A5,5,1)),"1 - monoton", 
IF(AND(MID(A5,8,1) <> MID(A5,5,1), MID(A5,2,1) <> MID(A5,5,1), MID(A5,2,1) <> MID(A5,8,1)), "3 - rainbow",
"2 - two tone"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((
MID(A5:A,8,1)=MID(A5:A,5,1))*(MID(A5:A,2,1)=MID(A5:A,5,1)),"1 - monoton", 
IF((MID(A5:A,8,1) <> MID(A5:A,5,1))*(MID(A5:A,2,1) <> MID(A5:A,5,1))*(MID(A5:A,2,1) <> MID(A5:A,8,1)), "3 - rainbow",
"2 - two tone")))
```